# Not Able To Get Sensor Readings on AM2302

Tags: sensor

I have an AM2302 from Adafruit. I have followed the directions on [ModMyPi](https://www.modmypi.com/blog/am2302-temphumidity-sensor). Which consisted of cloning https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_DHT.git via git. Installing build-essential and python-dev then running `sudo python setup.py install`. When I test the connection with the library I get `Failed to get reading. Try again!`. I have tried different GPIOs as well as both 3.3V pins. Each time I get the same result. I am not seeing anything relevant in the logs other then I am opening 'gpiomem device'.

```
pi@dapi:~/Projects/TempSensor/Adafruit_Python_DHT/examples $ sudo ./AdafruitDHT.py 2302 4
Failed to get reading. Try again!
```

I edited simpletest.py to reflect the proper sensor and pin and I receive the same result.

```
pi@dapi:~/Projects/TempSensor/Adafruit_Python_DHT/examples $ sudo python simpletest.py
Failed to get reading. Try again!
```

Answer (score 2):

Try different software.  There are plenty of choices if you google.

E.g. my [DHT11/21/22/33/44](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#pdif2_DHTXXD)  code.

## To build

`gcc -Wall -pthread -o DHTXXD test_DHTXXD.c DHTXXD.c -lpigpiod_if2`

## To start the daemom

`sudo pigpiod`

## To run

`./DHTXXD -g4 -i3 # connected to (Broadcom numbering) GPIO 4, every 3 seconds`

DHTXXD returns three values.  A status, the temperature, and the
humidity.  The status is one of the following.  0 (good)
indicates a successful read.  The other values indicate a read failure
and the last good read of temperature and humidity will be returned.

```
GOOD         0
BAD_CHECKSUM 1
BAD_DATA     2
TIMEOUT      3
```

Comment: Still not receiving anything. `pi@dapi:~/Projects/TempSensor/Adafruit_Python_DHT $ ./DHTXXD -g2 -i3
3 0.0 0.0`

Comment: @MrStatic Which GPIO are you using? My pigpio only uses Broadcom numbering so 2 refers to GPIO2 which is connected to pin 3. It's not the best choice as it has hard-wired 1k8 pull-ups to 3V3 fitted. For GPIO numbering see pinout.xyz (pin 1 is at the SD card end).

Comment: I have tried on 4 and 22. Both result in 0.0 0.0.

Comment: Either the sensors are faulty or you are not connecting them properly.  A close-up photo added to your question showing the connections would help.

Comment: [Here](http://imgur.com/a/x7JzU) are two photos. This was my more recent attempt so I moved to 26.